# C++ Implementing Linkedlist with multiple variables

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've started c++ programming 5weeks back.
I'm working on a program and using linkedlists to store data in the program. So for this is what I'm done and the program is not compiling. I will be glad if the community gives some idea in fixing these errors.

// C++ Assignment.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
// Global variables

string name;
int nic;
int contact;
string address;
int customerId;
string status;
string todaysVehicle;
string vnum;
string serviceType;

int GetInput()
{

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}


struct list
{
    string name;
    int nic;
    int contact;
    string address;
    int customerId;
    string status;
    string todaysVehicle;
    string vnum;
    string serviceType;
    list *next;
};

// List Function Prototypes

bool empty(list *head);
void DisplayMenu();
void firsttElement(list *&head, list *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum);
void insertCusomter(list *&head, list *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum);
void removeCustomer(list *&head, list *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum);
void customerList(list *current);


bool empty(list *head){
    if (head == NULL)
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}


// Main menu of the program

void DisplayMenu(){

}

void firstElement(list *&head, list *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum){
    list *temp1 = new list;
    temp1->nic = nic;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    head = temp1;
    last = temp1;

    list *temp2 = new list;
    temp2->name = name;
    temp2->next = NULL;
    head = temp2;
    last = temp2;

    list *temp3 = new list;
    temp3->nic = contact;
    temp3->next = NULL;
    head = temp3;
    last = temp3;

    list *temp4 = new list;
    temp4->address = address;
    temp4->next = NULL;
    head = temp4;
    last = temp4;

    list *temp5 = new list;
    temp5->nic = customerId;
    temp5->next = NULL;
    head = temp5;
    last = temp5;

    list *temp6 = new list;
    temp6->todaysVehicle = todaysVehicle;
    temp6->next = NULL;
    head = temp6;
    last = temp6;

    list *temp7 = new list;
    temp7->vnum = vnum;
    temp7->next = NULL;
    head = temp7;
    last = temp7;

}

void insertCustomer(list *&head, list *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum){
    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {

        list *temp = new list;
        temp->nic = nic;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }

    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {

        list *temp = new list;
        temp->name = name;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }

    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {

        list *temp = new list;
        temp->address = address;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }

    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {

        list *temp = new list;
        temp->nic = contact;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }

    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {

        list *temp = new list;
        temp->nic = customerId;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }

    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {

        list *temp = new list;
        temp->todaysVehicle = todaysVehicle;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }

    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {

        list *temp = new list;
        temp->vnum = vnum;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void removeCustomer(list *&head, list *&last){
    if (empty(head))
        cout << "There are no Customers in the Database! \n";

    else if (head == last){
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }
    else{
        list *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void customerList(list *current){
    if (empty(current))
        cout << "The list is empty \n;";
    else
    {
        cout << "The list contains: \n";
        while (current != NULL){
            cout << current->customerId << endl;
            cout << current->nic << endl;
            cout << current->name << endl;
            cout << current->vnum << endl;
            cout << current->todaysVehicle << endl;
            cout << current->vnum << endl;
            cout << current->contact << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }


}

// Main Fucntion

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[], void insertCustomer(list *&head, list *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum), void removeCustomer(list *&head, list *&last), void customerList(list *current)){

    list *head = NULL;
    list *last = NULL;
    int choice;

    do{
        system("cls");
        cout << "Clean Park Daily Car Services\n";
        cout << "******************************\n";
        cout << "Please make your selection\n";
        cout << " \n";
        cout << "1 - Register Customer\n";
        cout << "2 - Request for Serivce\n";
        cout << "3 - UnRegister Customer\n";
        cout << "4 - Update Customer\n";
        cout << "5 - View Customer\n";
        cout << "6 - View all Customers\n";
        cout << "7 - Exit\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Choice: ";

        cin >> choice;

        DisplayMenu();
        switch (choice){

        case 1: // Register a new customer
            system("CLS");
                cout << "PLease enter Customer National Id: \n";
                cin >> nic;
                cout << " Enter Customer Name: \n";
                cin >> name;
                cout << "Enter Customer Contact Number: \n";
                cin >> contact;
                cout << "Enter Customer Address: \n";
                cin >> address;
                cout << "Enter Customer Number: \n";
                cin >> customerId;
                cout << "Enter Vehicle's Date: \n";
                cin >> todaysVehicle;
                cout << "Enter Vehicle Number: \n";
                cin >> vnum;
                void insertCustomer(list *&head, list *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum);
            break;

        case 2: // Request for Service
            system("CLS");

        case 3: // Remove customer
            system("CLS");
            removeCustomer(*&head, *&last);
            break;

        case 4: // Update customer
            system("CLS");

        case 5: // View Customer
            system("CLS");

        case 6: // View All Customers
            system("CLS");
            void customerList(list *current);
            break;

        case 7: // Exit Application
            cout << "Goodbye!.." << endl;
            exit(0);

        default:
            cout << "System exit \n";
        }
    } while (choice != 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which of the many errors you listed would you like addressed first?

Comment: First step would be to switch to a compiler that gave an error message instead of just `not compiling` ! (Read: Post the error message... instead of just not compiling!)

Comment: Could you please include an error message, reduce the volume of code and specify your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is already a type `list` in namespace `std`. If you `using namespace std;` you can't declarate at type named `list`. You never should name any of your own types `list` and stay away from using namespace `std`.
Rename your type `list`to `mylist`, for example. Adapt your code like this:

```
... 

struct mylist;
mylist *next;

...

struct mylist
{
    ...
};

bool empty(mylist *head);

...

void firstElement(myList *&head, myList *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum){
    head = last = new myList;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->nic = nic;
    head->contact = contact;
    head->address = address;
    head->customerId = customerId;
    head->name = name;
    head->todaysVehicle = todaysVehicle;
    head->vnum = vnum;
    head->status = status;
    head->serviceType = serviceType;
}

void insertCustomer(myList *&head, myList *&last, int nic, string name, int contact, string address, int customerId, string todaysVehicle, string vnum){
    if (empty(head))
        firstElement(head, last, nic, name, contact, address, customerId, todaysVehicle, vnum);

    else {
        last->next = new myList;
        last = last->next;

        last->next = NULL;
        last->nic = nic;
        last->contact = contact;
        last->address = address;
        last->customerId = customerId;
        last->name = name;
        last->todaysVehicle = todaysVehicle;
        last->vnum = vnum;
        last->status = status;
        last->serviceType = serviceType;
    }
}
```

Apart from this I recommend to use `std::list` and not to do it your own.

Comment: *"You never should name any of your own types `list`"* - That's true, but staying away from `using namespace std` is even more important.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I've updated the code, would like to know whether the code is storing data, if so I'm having difficulty trying to print the full list which is mentioned in the 'case 6' of the main function.